For groups $F, G, H$, if $G \not\approx H$, does that mean $F \oplus G \not\approx F \oplus H$?
For context, we were asked to prove in my Abstract Algebra class that
$$\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9 \not\approx \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3, \tag{1}$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the group of integers under addition, $\oplus$ is the external direct product, and $\approx$ denotes group isomorphism ($\not\approx$ denotes the lack thereof). The proof in my class involved inspecting the possible orders of elements in each group, and by noticing that the group on the LHS can have an element of order 9, while the largest order an element from group on the RHS can have is 3. However, I noticed that $\mathbb{Z}_9 \not\approx \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$, since $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is cyclic but $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ is not cyclic because 3 and 3 are not coprime (see Theorem 9.21 from this link), and it seemed possible if you could "multiply both sides" of this by $\mathbb{Z}_3$, then it would yield $(1)$.
With this in mind, this motivated me to construct the the following proposition:

Let $F, G, H$ be groups. $F \oplus G \approx F \oplus H$ if and only if $G \approx H$.

That way, negating the proposition would yield that $G \not\approx H$ implies $F \oplus G \not\approx F \oplus H$. I managed to prove the backwards direction, that $G \approx H$ implies $F \oplus G \approx F \oplus H$, using the isomorphism $\Phi : F \oplus G \to F \oplus H$ defined by $\Phi((f, g)) = (f, \phi(g))$ for $f \in F, g \in G$, and with $\phi$ being an isomorphism from $G$ to $H$.
So far, however, I have not been able to find a way to prove the forward direction or disprove it with a counterexample. How could I approach this?
